# WFFM Email has no attachment

Tags: wffm

We are using ***Sitecore 8.2 update 7 with WFFM***. We are facing issues in LIVE site (Prod CD) while getting Emails, **the attachments are NOT there.**

**When we remove** the following config line in Sitecore.Forms.config

```
<setting name="WFM.IsRemoteActions" value="true"/>
```

**We are getting attachments, but our other form which has Custom Submit Action stops working.**

**My Current config in LIVE**

```
<setting name="WFM.IsRemoteActions" value="true"/> 
<setting name="WFM.MasterDatabase" value="master" /> <!-- if we make this as "web" the custom submit action stops working
```

**Inside Sitecore both Submit Actions (Custom and Send Email) have Client Action = [unchecked]**

Comment: Do you have `<IsIncludeAttachments>true</IsIncludeAttachments>` parameter added for send email message action?

Comment: What do you have in the configuration for: `/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Actions/Save Actions/Send Email Message`

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat - Yes its there.

Comment: @JuliusA - Sorry didn't get your question

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that your `/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Actions/Save Actions/Send Email Message` item has the required "include attachments" flag set.

In Parameters field verify you have the the following:

`<IsIncludeAttachments>true</IsIncludeAttachments>`

Comment: It is already there..!!